# Why does Jade think the link coming from my array should route the user to /admin/thisurl vs the actual link?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express, pug

In my jade file, I am iterating through an array that is connected to my mongo db. On a separate submission form, the user is able to submit a url which I eventually want to append to the `<a>` element in my jade file. As you can see I am trying to do this with (href=post.link target="_blank). So I iterate through the array, and grab the link and then try to put in in the `<a>` element.

However, when I click on the link on localhost, the route is cannot GET /admin/thisurl. Why is it putting my internal routes when I just want the link to open in a new tab to the website?

```
.fullPostContainer
   each post in posts
      .media.fullPostPadding
         a.removeTextDeco(href=post.link, target='_blank')
            .media-left.media-middle
               // <a href="#">
               img.media-object(src='/facebook-logo.png', alt='facebook logo')

            .media-body
                div#mainTitlePost.media-heading.postTitleFont= post.title
                div#mainShortDesc.descriptionFont= post.description
                button#fireBtn.btn.btn-sm.btnColor(type='button')
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if **thisurl** does not start with http://domain.tld  then **thisurl** is appended to current page url.

that means **thisurl** is considered relative url.

Comment: Accepted! Thank you again!